# reading mpeg-ts file to parallel port at 27Mhz

Tags: fpga, mpeg2-ts, dvb

I planed to read a MPEG-TS file from the SD card and write it to an 8-bit parallel output as mpeg transport with a 27 MHz clock (simple FPGA-based MPEG-TS tester for DVB purposes). But I can,t calculate speed of writing packets in out port and how many null-packets I need insert into out port. Can you help me?

Comment: I found what PCR value is 42 bits long
and incremented with a frequency of 27 MHz -> when i must calculate a delta between two PCR and send paсket if delta is new value?

Comment: Not all packets have a PCR so you need to interpolate the delta to avoid bursts.